# How do I simulate z-fighting of low poly against high poly for a single mesh?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I'm fairly new to shading and materials. While playing around with my low poly and high poly model I came across this effect, and I really like it. I got it like this by viewing both models at the same time so both their surfaces peek through. Is this something that can be done with procedural shading? I'd like to apply this as a material on my low poly model.

[image: picture of desired effect]

[image: picture of material nodes]

Comment: Is baking to a texture a satisfying workflow? Ideally please provide your .blend file.

Comment: I need to use the model in unreal engine. So ideally I need to bake it. Unfortunately I cannot provide the .blend file

Answer (score 2):

On your high poly you could emit the object space position:

[image]

Bake that onto low poly UV space, float32 linear image texture, and use it in the low poly to differentiate between the two colors:

[image]

The *Greater Than* threshold is arbitrary:

[image]

In a more realistic scenario (yours) instead of mixing flat colors, you want to mix another baked image texture from high poly, with the original color of the low poly.